# Quais chcp existem ou como posso saber quais tenho?

Tags: batch

Eu estou vendo um pouco sobre batch, e gostaria de saber quais páginas de código existem ou onde encontrá-las. Até o momento, encontrei as seguintes CHCP usando um script de bruteforce

````
set var=%1
:loopset
title current=%var%
echo %var%> %temp%\varlist.txt
chcp %var% 2>nul
if "%errorlevel%" equ "0" echo CHCP %var% founded!>>chcp.txt
if "%var%" equ "999999" goto end
set /a var=%var%+1
goto loopset
:end```

CHCP 37 founded!
CHCP 437 founded!
CHCP 500 founded!CHCP 708 founded!
CHCP 720 founded!
CHCP 737 founded!
CHCP 775 founded!
CHCP 850 founded!
CHCP 852 founded!
CHCP 855 founded!
CHCP 857 founded!
CHCP 858 founded!
CHCP 860 founded!
CHCP 861 founded!
CHCP 862 founded!
CHCP 863 founded!
CHCP 864 founded!
CHCP 865 founded!
CHCP 866 founded!
CHCP 869 founded!
CHCP 870 founded!
CHCP 874 founded!
CHCP 875 founded!
CHCP 1026 founded!
CHCP 1140 founded! 
CHCP 1141 founded! 
CHCP 1047 founded!
CHCP 1142 founded! 
CHCP 1142 founded! 
CHCP 1143 founded! 
CHCP 1144 founded! 
CHCP 1145 founded! 
CHCP 1146 founded! 
CHCP 1147 founded! 
CHCP 1148 founded! 
CHCP 1149 founded! 
CHCP 1250 founded!
CHCP 1251 founded!
CHCP 1252 founded!
CHCP 1253 founded!
CHCP 1254 founded!
CHCP 1255 founded!
CHCP 1256 founded!
CHCP 1257 founded!
CHCP 1258 founded!
CHCP 1361 founded!
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP  founded! 
CHCP 10000 founded!
CHCP 10001 founded!
CHCP 10002 founded!
CHCP 10003 founded!
CHCP 10004 founded!
CHCP 10005 founded!
CHCP 10006 founded!
CHCP 10007 founded!
CHCP 10008 founded!
CHCP 10010 founded!
CHCP 10017 founded!
CHCP 10021 founded!
CHCP 10029 founded!
CHCP 10079 founded!
CHCP 10081 founded!
CHCP 10082 founded!
CHCP 20000 founded!
CHCP 20001 founded!
CHCP 20002 founded!
CHCP 20003 founded!
CHCP 20004 founded!
CHCP 20005 founded!
CHCP 20105 founded!
CHCP 20106 founded!
CHCP 20107 founded!
CHCP 20108 founded!
CHCP 20127 founded!
CHCP 20261 founded!
CHCP 20269 founded!
CHCP 20273 founded! 
CHCP 20277 founded! 
CHCP 20278 founded! 
CHCP 20280 founded! 
CHCP 20284 founded! 
CHCP 20285 founded! 
CHCP 20290 founded! 
CHCP 20297 founded! 
CHCP 20420 founded! 
CHCP 20423 founded! 
CHCP 20424 founded! 
CHCP 20833 founded! 
CHCP 20838 founded! 
CHCP 20866 founded!
CHCP 20871 founded! 
CHCP 20880 founded! 
CHCP 20905 founded! 
CHCP 20924 founded! 
CHCP 20932 founded!
CHCP 20936 founded!
CHCP 20949 founded!
CHCP 21025 founded! 
CHCP 21027 founded! 
CHCP 21866 founded!
CHCP 28591 founded!
CHCP 28592 founded!
CHCP 28593 founded!
CHCP 28594 founded!
CHCP 28595 founded!
CHCP 28596 founded!
CHCP 28597 founded!
CHCP 28598 founded!
CHCP 28599 founded!
CHCP 28603 founded!
CHCP 28605 founded!
CHCP 38598 founded!
CHCP 50220 founded!
CHCP 50221 founded!
CHCP 50222 founded!
CHCP 50225 founded!
CHCP 50227 founded!
CHCP 50229 founded!
CHCP 51949 founded!
CHCP 52936 founded!
CHCP 54936 founded!
CHCP 55000 founded! 
CHCP 55001 founded! 
CHCP 55002 founded! 
CHCP 55003 founded! 
CHCP 55004 founded! 
CHCP 57002 founded!
CHCP 57003 founded!
CHCP 57004 founded!
CHCP 57005 founded!
CHCP 57006 founded!
CHCP 57007 founded!
CHCP 57008 founded!
CHCP 57009 founded!
CHCP 57010 founded!
CHCP 57011 founded!
CHCP 65000 founded+ACE-CHCP 65001 founded!
````

Comment: Não que isso vá fazer diferença, mas provavelmente cada PC tem uns codepages diferentões e que eu não listei, logo, se quiserem usar/melhorar meu script, à vonts. ;).

Answer (score 0):

Esqueçam, eu fiz essa pergunta em 22:00, mas por algum motivo a página só postou agora há pouco e eu achei minha resposta:
`Win+R > Regedit.exe > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Nls >  Codepage`
Ou
`Win+R > cmd.exe > reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage"`
Ambos nos mostram/devolvem os valores de todas as codepages *do PC.*
E, a ponto de curiosidade, meu script conseguiu achar todos, até uns não listados, como o 65000 e 65001, o que é curioso... Por que o codepage não lista esses?...
Bem, de qualquer forma, o texto abaixo mostra todos os codepages que eu achei (testei todos):

```
 37 
 437 
 500 
 708 
 720 
 737 
 775 
 850 
 852 
 855 
 857 
 858 
 860 
 861 
 862 
 863 
 864 
 865 
 866 
 869 
 870 
 874 
 875 
 1026 
 1140  
 1141  
 1047 
 1142  
 1142  
 1143  
 1144  
 1145  
 1146  
 1147  
 1148  
 1149  
 1250 
 1251 
 1252 
 1253 
 1254 
 1255 
 1256 
 1257 
 1258 
 1361 
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
 10000 
 10001 
 10002 
 10003 
 10004 
 10005 
 10006 
 10007 
 10008 
 10010 
 10017 
 10021 
 10029 
 10079 
 10081 
 10082 
 20000 
 20001 
 20002 
 20003 
 20004 
 20005 
 20105 
 20106 
 20107 
 20108 
 20127 
 20261 
 20269 
 20273  
 20277  
 20278  
 20280  
 20284  
 20285  
 20290  
 20297  
 20420  
 20423  
 20424  
 20833  
 20838  
 20866 
 20871  
 20880  
 20905  
 20924  
 20932 
 20936 
 20949 
 21025  
 21027  
 21866 
 28591 
 28592 
 28593 
 28594 
 28595 
 28596 
 28597 
 28598 
 28599 
 28603 
 28605 
 38598 
 50220 
 50221 
 50222 
 50225 
 50227 
 50229 
 51949 
 52936 
 54936 
 55000  
 55001  
 55002  
 55003  
 55004  
 57002 
 57003 
 57004 
 57005 
 57006 
 57007 
 57008 
 57009 
 57010 
 57011 
 65000 +ACE-
 65001
```